# Не отображаются номера страниц в GridView (aspx)

Tags: c#, gridview, asp, aspx

На странице выводится GridView.

Установлены свойства 
    PageSize="5" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="..."
а также свойства отображения пейджера

На странице сам пейджер отображается, но доступны только кнопки вперед, назад, первая и последняя страницы, как будто используется Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast".

Данные для GridView берутся из DataSet (но есть и из DataSource).

Само переключение страниц работает.

Есть ли глобальная настройка определяющая отображение пейджера для грида и/или
как заставить его показать номера страниц?

- Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
- X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
- X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Спасибо

Comment: `а также свойства отображения пейджера` какие?

Comment: `<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="5" />`